# NIFI:how to get custom log files by tailFail?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have    nifi-1.3.0-RC1 and  i want  to get  log  files  i used  this  :

```
 nifi-1.3.0-RC1/logs/nifi-app.log
```

but   tailFail processor   throws and exception :**Java.nio.file.NosuchFieleExcption** maybe this  version of  nifi collects its  log  file  somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The log files are kept in a directory under `$NIFI_HOME`, which is the directory containing the `bin`, `conf`, `lib`, `logs`, etc. directories that Apache NiFi runs from. You can determine this directory by running

If you built NiFi from source, it will be a directory path like:

```
/Users/alopresto/Workspace/nifi/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/nifi-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If you downloaded the binary, it will be something like (after unzipping/untarring):

```
/Users/alopresto/Downloads/nifi-1.3.0/
```

It's a good idea to use the absolute path for the filesystem rather than the relative path you have above.